# Android's touchscreen key events on Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, android, input, touch-screen

I am working on a [Halium](https://halium.org) port for an Android device that has a Synaptics touchscreen [(synaptics_dsx](https://github.com/Halium/android_kernel_asus_T00F/tree/halium-7.1/drivers/external_drivers/drivers/input/touchscreen/asus_synaptics_dsx) driver). The port is on a mature stage, has a Wayland compositor running, and the apps are provided with correct touch, swipe, and pinch events.

However, I fail to make use of Android-style (back, home, recent) buttons on the touchscreen. With evtest, I can see that the input source is capable of `KEY_HOME`, `KEY_MENU`, and `KEY_BACK` events, but these are not emitted when I touch the responsible areas; instead, I get the usual set of touch events (`ABS_MT_POSITION_{X,Y}`, `ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID`, `BTN_TOUCH`, `BTN_TOOL_FINGER`).

I have done an extensive web and source code search but still cannot find the reason I do not get correct events. I would be grateful if you could point me to a fix or a way to debug.

Comment: You don't get the "correct" events because there aren't any actual buttons, just pictures.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So, you think these events should not be sent at all?

Comment: I think that when running Android the button presses are handled in software.

Comment: Android maps keycodes to its internal names through `/system/usr/keylayout` files: https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files. The codes it uses are defined in the kernel. The driver makes use of these codes in a device-specific manner (https://github.com/Halium/android_kernel_asus_T00F/blob/36a7f6a77b568facd200d6e5441019c81e6dba60/drivers/external_drivers/drivers/input/touchscreen/asus_synaptics_dsx/synaptics_dsx_core.c#L2695), which makes me think vendors have to implement key support themselves.